# how can I capture m8u3/rtmp with nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, video-streaming, html5-video

I've been working on a little hobby project, and I was wondering if anyone can tell me if its possible (and possibly how?) to make node.js capture a m8u3 video stream (with audio) and save it on disk? I have a URL which gives a m8u3 stream as well as a rtmp. I haven't been able to find any viable solution.

Thanks :)

Comment: you can use a http stream piped to a fs stream

Comment: I'm fairly new to nodejs, but seriously can it be that easy? :)

Comment: I do not know the technical details of the video stream data structure relative to the video file data structure, but in theory yes it is that easy. It would be good if you provide more details about what you've tried so I could help you to choose the right way to do this.

Comment: Lets say I want to capture this stream in nodejs: 
http://walterebert.com/playground/video/hls/sintel-trailer.m3u8

Comment: you should check out: https://www.npmjs.com/package/m3u8